# How to filter numbers based on range?

Tags: python

I have a list in which some numbers are like this:

```
["0022", "1144", "1355", "0251"...]
```

These numbers represent times, `0022` represents `12:22` and so on.

Now I need to filter these times based on hours. For example, I have a range between 2 am and 4 am, therefore I need `0251` to be in this range(as it represents 02:51).

I tried doing the following:

```
 for i in mylist:
        if(i in range(200,400)):
            print(i)
        if(i in range(1000,1200)):
            print(i)
```

I did this since I thought `0251` can be interpreted as `251`, but I get no output from that. The second if statment should return `1144`.

I am trying to really not use ANY package or module, I want my code to be free from packages and modules... any assistance is greatly appreciated..

Comment: `if(int(i) in range(200,400)):` ?

Comment: print out i, len(i), type(i). are they what you expect them to be?

Answer (score 2):

Your list contains strings and your code is trying to filter on numeric values. Convert them to integers first.

```
mylist = [int(i) for i in mylist]
for i in mylist:
     ....etc...
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue with your current code is you're looking if the *string* representing the time is in a range of *integers*.

The safest thing to do would be to convert it to a time and then check the range of that times hour

```
from datetime import datetime
for i in mylist:
    hour = datetime.strptime(i, '%H%M').hour
    if 2 < hour < 4:
         print(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

Id assume since you are using 200-400 as indices of the list (so mylist[200]-mylist[400]). instead I would do smth like

```
for i in mylist:
    if int(i)>200 and int(i)<400:
        print(i)
    elif int(i)>1000 and int(i)<1200:
        print(i)
```